# Getting auto-increment value as 0 in hibernate after insert

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am getting only 0 as the auto-increment value (primary key) after database insert in hibernate. Please see the code below

```
Session session = HibernateSession.getHibernateSession();//Singleton class
Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();
Ticket ticket = new Ticket();
ticket.setTicket_desc("This is ticket description 5");
session.save(ticket);
//session.persist(ticket);
t.commit();
System.out.println("Created ticket id is " + ticket.getTicket_id());
```

Below is the xml mapping

[image: XML mapping]

In the database side - mysql, I can see the auto-increment working correctly, I am not sure why I am getting only 0 in java. I have also tried with session.persist(). Can you imagine where am I going wrong?

Comment: Call `session.refresh(ticket)` before you access the ID.  Let us know if you can't figure it out after reading the duplicate link.

Comment: If the id is auto increment, you can try to add this to your xml mapping instead of the generator class: <generated-value strategy="IDENTITY" />

Comment: Using session.refresh(ticket) is throwing me this exception ---> Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.UnresolvableObjectException: No row with the given identifier exists: [com.bosch.database.tables.Ticket#0]

Comment: Using <generated-value strategy="IDENTITY" /> instead of  <generator class="assigned" ></generator>   throws xml error in eclipse @June

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen, I am sorry but I  could not figure out the from the link that you have marked as duplicate.

Comment: If the auto increment is working correctly in MySQL, then my guess is that the Hibernate session is not updating.

Comment: I have identified the issue,  <generator class="identity"></generator>  fixed the issue. @June thanks, you were close.